# What is the emulsification power of 1 egg yolk?

Tags: eggs, emulsion, hollandaise

How much oil (fat) can one egg yolk hold safely before you risk the sauce breaking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surprisingly high -- [something like 6 gallons of oil](http://www.vendian.org/envelope/dir1/mayo.html) can be emulsified by a single egg yolk.  In addition to the site linked, I've seen similar experiments by Kenji Lopez-Alt and James Petersen.

So if your mayonnaise refuses to emulsify, it's NOT because it doesn't have enough egg yolks.