# Protein in mayonnaise...none?

Tags: nutrient-composition, mayonnaise

I was looking at a Hellman's real mayonnaise jar with whole eggs and yolks, and the nutrition label says there are 0 grams of protein. How is that possible? Is this common for mayonnaise in general?

Comment: Probably due to rounding off of the numbers - if you use only very little egg you can get below 0.5%. We have a question [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55920/what-is-the-emulsification-power-of-1-egg-yolk) that deals with how much oil one egg can bind. Welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just rounding. The [Hellman's nutrition](http://www.hellmanns.com/product/detail/97847/real-mayonnaise) matches the [USDA generic mayonnaise nutrition](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/624?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=35&offset=&sort=&qlookup=04025) very closely for the single serving size (1 tbsp, 13.8g), but the USDA one also includes amounts per 100g. It's 0.96g protein per 100g, and when scaled down to the serving size that's only 0.13g and gets rounded to 0.